# Changing Image file

Tags: image

I need to change an image file in our landing page, I have found the image which is saved in Style Library, I just not too sure how I can change the path to the new image. Where would be the path?
Regards

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Where is this image added on page? In which web part? Can you please add any screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how it was embedded, if you have custom branding probably easiest would be to replace the file with you new image (have the same name). If it is embeded in content web part on the home page just edit that web part.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I have replaced the image with the new file, however when I change IE zooming from 100 to 75 the image doesn't stretch out fully. Please see the new Image I have added.

Comment: Not sure what desired outcome is for you. The image you attached doesn't tell me much.

Comment: the desire outcome is the green image bar stretched and cover the all page length